# Shell argument inside regular expression

Tags: regex, linux, shell

I currently have the following regex inside a shell script which kills a process matching a certain regex, which works ok:

```
 killall --regexp 'docker(.*?)[logs\ \-f\ liberty]$'
```

I'm trying to change the last part, basically instead of the string 'liberty', have it match the command line argument 1 to the script.. I read that the '\' character can escape things inside regex, so I tried the following but didn't have any luck:

```
  killall --regexp 'docker(.*?)[logs\ \-f\ \$1]$'
```

Am I not escaping it properly or do I need to store it in a temp variable etc. ?

Comment: `killall --regexp 'docker(.*?)[logs\ \-f\ '"$1"']$'`

Comment: Variables aren't expanded inside single quotes, only inside double quotes.

Comment: Thanks @WilliamPursell - That worked :)